# Bounding the cheeger constant (isoperimetric number)

Tags: probability, graph-theory, random-graphs, spectral-graph-theory, path-connected

During my research on Cheeger constant, I've noticed that there are many formulas to represent this constant like:
$$ h = \min\frac{|E(X,\bar{X})|}{\min (vol(X),vol(\bar{X}))} $$
or
$$ h= \min \frac{|\partial X|}{|X|} $$ where $|\partial X|$ represent the number of edges between the boundary of $X$ and the boundary of $\bar{X}$. In addition to other formulas.

Now, I am interested in the formula presented [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.87.7114&rep=rep1&type=pdf) to represent the Cheeger constant. It is mentioned that
$$ h = \inf \frac{|\partial S|}{|S|} $$ where $|\partial S|$ is the number of edges having precisely one endpoint in the set $S$ and the other endpoint in $\bar{S}$ and for sure this the same definition of $|\partial X|$ in the previous formula.

**My Question**

In bounding the Cheeger constant in [the 2nd page of the same article](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.87.7114&rep=rep1&type=pdf), the author bounded $|\partial S|$ in the following way:

$$ |\partial S_1|\geq \frac{2|S_1||S_2|}{2(k-1)} $$
which is the number of paths of length 2 between any two vertices in $S_1$ and $S_2$ divided by the number of paths of length 2 in which a given edge can reside.

***What I don't understand***

Logically, what is the relation between $|\partial S_1|$ and this fraction (the number of paths of length 2 between any two vertices in $S_1$ and $S_2$ divided by the number of paths of length 2 in which a given edge can reside) i.e on what basis he represented the ***number of edges*** between two bipartite sets ***by the number of paths*** between those sets or how he replaced the edges by the paths!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two assumptions made on the graph where this bound applies:

1. The graph is $k$-regular (which is standard);
2. Between any two vertices $v_1$ and $v_2$, there are exactly two paths of length $2$; this is certainly not true in general.

Given these assumptions, here's how we prove the bound. We take a partition $V = S_1 \cup S_2$, and want to bound $|\partial S_1| = |E(S_1, S_2)|$. Choose any two vertices $v_1 \in S_1$ and $v_2 \in S_2$. Any path of length $2$ from $v_1$ to $v_2$ contains exactly one edge of $\partial S_1$: the path will go from $v_1$ to $w$ to $v_2$ for some third vertex $w$, and either $w \in S_1$ (in which case $(w,v_2)$ is an edge of $\partial S_1$) or $w \in S_2$ (in which case $(v_1, w)$ is an edge of $\partial S_1$).

There are $|S_1||S_2|$ choices of $v_1 \in S_1$ and $v_2 \in S_2$, and two paths from $v_1$ to $v_2$ for each choice, so we get $2|S_1||S_2|$ paths total, each containing an edge of $\partial S_1$.

We divide by $2(k-1)$ because each edge of $\partial S_1$ may end up counted many times. Each edge is counted at most $2(k-1)$ times, because any edge of the graph is contained in at most $2(k-1)$ paths of length $2$: we can extend the edge in one of $2$ directions by one of $k-1$ other neighbors of that endpoint.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is a perfect answer.